# How to properly use UUID with Doctrine when using MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, uuid

We have created a simple project using a default distribution ApiPlatform 2.6 (Symfony 6, Postgres 13).
Our entities use UUID type for primary keys like:

```
#[ApiResource()]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'abc')]
class Abc {
    /**
     * @var Uuid|null The id 
     */
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: "doctrine.uuid_generator")]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'abc_id', type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    private ?Uuid $id;

    public function getId(): ?Uuid {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @var Abd 
     */
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Abd::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "abc_abd_id", referencedColumnName: "abd_id", nullable: false)]
    public Abd $abd;
}

#[ApiResource()]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'abd')]
class Abd {
    /**
     * @var Uuid|null The id 
     */
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: "doctrine.uuid_generator")]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'abd_id', type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    private ?Uuid $id;

    public function getId(): ?Uuid {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var string Name
     */
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'abd_name')]
    public $name;

}
```

We have created a query like this:

```
$abd = $entityManager->getRepository(VeterinaryClinic::class)->findOneBy(["name" => "test"]);
assert($abd != null);
$entities = $entityManager->getRepository(Abc::class)->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->andWhere('c.abd = :abd')
    ->setParameter('abd', $abd)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

When using Postgres database this works fine and returns results, however, on MySQL database, it returns nothing.

I have checked the logs and the generated query has this comparison:

```
WHERE v0_.abd_id = '13316c9e-efc3-410c-880d-ead8d702e3df'
```

On Postgres, it works fine, but when using MySQL it fails.
I would assume that the Doctrine query builder will convert the values, but it seems it does not.
Is there something else I could do to make queries like this work when using MySQL? Without refactoring all queries?

Comment: `$abd` is an object, not an id. It's not a typo, the property is called `abd` so the where clause is ok. It is the symfony built in UUID handling.

Comment: I use UUID for primary key also and got problem when showing id data when using findAll or findBy to query entity list. How to convert id field into string in the query result?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the issue is related only to the query builder.
Using EntityManager's functions:

- find
- findBy
- getReference

work fine when sending the string.
It's only when using query builder I have to use the binary form.
So in my example, changing:

```
 ->setParameter('abd', $abd)
```

to:

```
 ->setParameter('abd', $abd->getId()->toBinary)
```

solves the issue.

The query looks similar to this now:

```
WHERE v1_.abd_id = 0x13316C9EEFC3410C880DEAD8D702E3DF
```

Unfortunately, this most likely means it will not work on Postgres anymore, but I have not tested it.

I've created a bug report https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/10017

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue when starting a new project with MySQL (I was previously using PostgreSQL).

Using **->toBinary** works, but I did not like the idea of a DBMS specific solution.

After some research I found the solution on the Symfony documentation itself:

```
->setParameter('user', $user->getUuid(), UuidType::NAME)
```

or directly:

```
->setParameter('user', $user->getUuid(), 'uuid')
```

source: [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/uid.html#storing-uuids-in-databases)